# What is the most efficient way to connect to MySQL across multiple files in Python?

Tags: python, mysql

I have a Python app spread across several files, with one main application and (let's call it main.py) and several modules which are imported by main.py (let's call them module_a.py and module_b.py)

What is the most efficient way to connect to MySQL database across all these files?

Shall I create seperate a module *database.py*, connect to the database in that module, and import this module to every single file, and then use:

```
//database.py
db=MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",user="xxx",passwd="yyy",db="zzz")

//main.py
import database
cur = database.db.cursor()

//module_a.py
import database
cur = database.db.cursor()
```

Or shall I connect to the database in every single file separately?

Or maybe there are other options, even more suitable for this purpose?

Comment: I'm not explicitly answering your question, but I would *definitely* recommend [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) for any database operations.

Comment: Will you be executing multiple queries in parallel or is a singleton/borg pattern an option?

Comment: Related to your question, although not what you asked: You don't loose  any performance in Python by re-importing a module from any sub-module in our app. The "database.py" file would be parsed just once during your application lifetime either way.

Comment: @Blender: Actually, I think "use sqlalchemy" is a very explicit and direct answer to this question as it is written.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip to use SQLAlchemy! I never heard about it, and I will definitely look into it. I might be running queries in parallel in the future, although I'm not doing that at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion database.py would do the trick with connection pooling (what is probably the only thing you're looking for ? Amirite?)

Comment: I agree with this guy. Make a file and have functions like open() close() etc

Comment: @wojciechz Yes, connection pooling is exactly what I'm trying to do. Thanks for your answer, I will definitely try it

Comment: @Peter I don't really understand open() and close() suggestion. Do you suggest creating seperate functions to close and open db connection? I hoped, that once opened, at the beginning (by main.py) it can remain open whole time (as long as I'm using this db, which is all the time)

Comment: maintining a permament connection to the database is not that efficient for your application. Ofcourse some live applications need to be open all the time.